# How to intercept redux-saga depending on api response status?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, redux-saga

In my react-native project, I want to handle 204 (no content error) response globally after getting response from api request and navigate to screen. How should I do to intercept in saga?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your api call in a below generator function which will intercept 204 from your response and navigate to needed screen

```
 export function* callApi(apiCall) {
      const response = yield apiCall;
      if (!isNoContent(response)) {
        return response;
      }
      //navigate to screen
      return response;
    }

    function isNoContent(resp) {
      return (
        resp.status === 204
      );
  }

const apiCall = call(apiRequestService, payload);
const json = yield call(callApi, apiCall);
```

Comment: Yes. This is a way to handle for reponse. But, this flow isn't exactly the one that I want. If so, I have to call isNoContent() function after calling every api request. I just want to intercept for saga at some effects, as in effectMiddlewares described in v1-beta release notes - https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.0